# bug in the contract/I cant deploy but I dont see it it fails when I want to deploy it its not a gas problem

Tags: solidity, error, gas-limit, bug, failed-transaction

```
/**
 *Submitted for verification at Etherscan.io on 2023-04-24
*/

/*

Your Name Token is a cryptocurrency inspired by the popular anime movie "Your Name", 
which has gained the admiration of many fans around the world, including Elon Musk, 
who has publicly expressed on Twitter that it is his all-time favorite anime. 
This unique token aims to bring the excitement and emotional connection of the film to the world of crypto.
The token has a total supply of 10 millions and is built on the Ethereum network as an ERC-20 token.

https://t.me/your_name_eth


*/

// SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicensed
pragma solidity 0.8.18;

abstract contract Context {
    function _msgSender() internal view virtual returns (address) {
        return msg.sender;
    }
}

interface IERC20 {
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);
    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom( address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}

library SafeMath {
    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 c = a + b;
        require(c >= a, "addition overflow");
        return c;
    }

    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return sub(a, b, "subtraction overflow");
    }

    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b, string memory errorMessage) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b <= a, errorMessage);
        uint256 c = a - b;
        return c;
    }

    function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        if (a == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        uint256 c = a * b;
        require(c / a == b, " multiplication overflow");
        return c;
    }

    function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return div(a, b, "division by zero");
    }

    function div(uint256 a, uint256 b, string memory errorMessage) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b > 0, errorMessage);
        uint256 c = a / b;
        return c;
    }
}

contract Ownable is Context {
    address private _owner;
    event OwnershipTransferred(
        address indexed previousOwner,
        address indexed newOwner
    );

    constructor() {
        address msgSender = _msgSender();
        _owner = msgSender;
        emit OwnershipTransferred(address(0), msgSender);
    }

    function owner() public view returns (address) {
        return _owner;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(_owner == _msgSender(), "caller is not the owner");
        _;
    }

    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public onlyOwner {
        require(newOwner != address(0), "new owner is the zero address");
        _owner = newOwner;
        emit OwnershipTransferred(_owner, newOwner);
    }

    function renounceOwnership() public virtual onlyOwner {
        emit OwnershipTransferred(_owner, address(0));
        _owner = address(0);
    }
}

interface IUniswapV2Factory {
    function createPair(address tokenA, address tokenB)
        external
        returns (address pair);
}

interface IUniswapV2Router02 {
    function swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        uint256 amountIn,
        uint256 amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint256 deadline
    ) external;

    function factory() external pure returns (address);
    function WETH() external pure returns (address);
}

contract ERC20Token is Context, IERC20, Ownable {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    mapping(address => uint256) private _balance;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) private _allowances;
    mapping(address => bool) private _isExcludedFromFeeWallet;
    uint256 private constant MAX = ~uint256(0);
    uint256 private _tax;

    // CHANGE DECIMALS HERE. Ex: 6 instead of 18
    uint8 private constant _decimals = 18;

    //CHANGE TOTAL SUPPLY HERE. Ex: 1000 instead of 1000000000000
    uint256 private constant _totalSupply = 1000000000000 * 10**_decimals;

    //CHANGE TOKEN NAME HERE. Ex: "My Token" instead of "Boom"
    string private constant _name = "Boom";

    //CHANGE SYMBOL HERE. Ex: "MTN" instead of "Boom"
    string private constant _symbol = "Boom";

    //CHANGE BUY TAX HERE. Ex: For 10% tax, 10 instead of 5
    uint256 public buyTax = 5;

     //CHANGE SELL TAX HERE. Ex: For 10% tax, 10 instead of 5
    uint256 public sellTax = 5;

    //CHANGE TAX WALLET HERE. Ex: 0x50d2594A7543ca49275A79e673f93A911fe4aE3Y instead of 0x60d2594A7543ca49275A79e673f93A911fe4aFA5
    address public taxWallet = payable(0x60d2594A7543ca49275A79e673f93A911fe4aFA5);

    // CHANGE MAX THEY CAN HOLD. Ex: for 10%, 10 instead of 1
    uint256 public MAX_PERCENT = 1;

    //CHANGE ANTI SNIPE TAX % FOR FIRST 3 BLOCKS. Ex: for 100%, 100 instead of 99
    uint256 public BOT_TAX = 99;



    uint256 public MAX_PER_WALLET = _totalSupply * MAX_PERCENT / 100;

    IUniswapV2Router02 private uniswapV2Router;
    address public uniswapV2Pair;

        
    uint256 private launchBlock;
    uint256 private deadBlock = 3;
    bool private launch = false;


    constructor() {
        uniswapV2Router = IUniswapV2Router02(0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D);
        uniswapV2Pair = IUniswapV2Factory(uniswapV2Router.factory()).createPair(address(this), uniswapV2Router.WETH());
        _balance[_msgSender()] = _totalSupply;
        
        _isExcludedFromFeeWallet[_msgSender()] = true;
        _isExcludedFromFeeWallet[address(this)] = true;
        _isExcludedFromFeeWallet[taxWallet] = true;


        emit Transfer(address(0), _msgSender(), _totalSupply);
    }

    function updateSellTax(uint256 _newValue) public onlyOwner {
        sellTax = _newValue;
    }

        function updateBuyTax(uint256 _newValue) public onlyOwner {
        buyTax = _newValue;
    }

    function updateMaxPercent(uint256 _newValue) public onlyOwner {
        MAX_PERCENT = _newValue;
    }

    function updateTaxWallet(address _newAddr) public onlyOwner {
        taxWallet = payable(_newAddr);
    }

    function updateBotTax(uint256 _newValue) public onlyOwner {
        BOT_TAX = _newValue;
    }




    function name() public pure returns (string memory) {
        return _name;
    }

    function symbol() public pure returns (string memory) {
        return _symbol;
    }

    function decimals() public pure returns (uint8) {
        return _decimals;
    }

    function totalSupply() public pure override returns (uint256) {
        return _totalSupply;
    }

    function balanceOf(address account) public view override returns (uint256) {
        return _balance[account];
    }

    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount)public override returns (bool){
        _transfer(_msgSender(), recipient, amount);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view override returns (uint256){
        return _allowances[owner][spender];
    }

    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) public override returns (bool){
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, amount);
        return true;
    }

    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) public override returns (bool) {
        _transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
        _approve(sender,_msgSender(),_allowances[sender][_msgSender()].sub(amount,"low allowance"));
        return true;
    }

    function _approve(address owner, address spender, uint256 amount) private {
        require(owner != address(0) && spender != address(0), "approve zero address");
        _allowances[owner][spender] = amount;
        emit Approval(owner, spender, amount);
    }

    function enableTrading() external onlyOwner {
        launch = true;
        launchBlock = block.number;
    }

    function _transfer(address from, address to, uint256 amount) private {
        require(from != address(0), "transfer zero address");
        bool _isBuy = false;
        bool _isSell = false;

        if(to != owner() && to != uniswapV2Pair && to != taxWallet){
            require(_balance[from] + amount < MAX_PER_WALLET, "Amount exceeds max per wallet limits");
        }

        if (_isExcludedFromFeeWallet[from] || _isExcludedFromFeeWallet[to]) {
            _tax = 0;
        } else {
            require(launch, "Wait till launch");
            if (block.number < launchBlock + deadBlock) {_tax=BOT_TAX;} else {
                if (from == uniswapV2Pair) {
                    _tax = buyTax;
                    _isBuy = true;
                } else if (to == uniswapV2Pair) {
                    _tax = sellTax;
                    _isSell = true;
                } else {
                    _tax = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        //transfer tokens
        uint256 taxTokens = (amount * _tax) / 100;
        uint256 transferAmount = amount - taxTokens;

        _balance[from] = _balance[from] - amount;
        _balance[to] = _balance[to] + transferAmount;

        if(_isBuy || _isSell){
            swapTokensForEth(taxTokens);
            payable(taxWallet).transfer(IERC20(uniswapV2Router.WETH()).balanceOf(address(this)));
        }
        

        emit Transfer(from, to, transferAmount);
    }

     function swapTokensForEth(uint256 tokenAmount) private {
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = address(this);
        path[1] = uniswapV2Router.WETH();
        _approve(address(this), address(uniswapV2Router), tokenAmount);
        uniswapV2Router.swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
            tokenAmount,
            0,
            path,
            taxWallet,
            block.timestamp
        );
    }


    receive() external payable {}
}
```

Comment: That is a huge chunk of code, with terrible layout, almost no explanation of the problem and the error message wasn't shared.

There is little anyone could do with such a thing.
Please review your question correctly,maybe share a link to your github repo instead of copy/pasting here, show the error message and narrow the target of your question

Comment: The bug is in the constructor. Likely your are using the wrong router.